# Redirecting all JSON requests made by a website to another URL

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I have this script that I use on tampermonkey

```
const origOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (...args) {
    if (typeof args[1] === 'string')
        args[1] = args[1].replace('example.com/*', 'mywebsite.com/*');
    }
    return origOpen.apply(this, args);
};
```

This script works completely fine for specific file URLs but not for redirecting all routes under an URL. This is not for redirecting a page completely. I want to know how can I redirect every single request that happens under `example.com` to `mywebsite.com`.

Comment: Did you try to log out the requests that do not get replaced to see why? It's almost certain that most XHR requests are not specified by full URL.

Comment: Well specific URLs that you add yourself are working completely fine but when I try to redirect all requests under that URL, nothing happens. The website continues to use it's own original content.

Comment: You did not understand my question. I was asking if you tried to do a `console.log` or a debug break for URLs that are failing to be replaced. I already posted an answer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Two problems

#### Problem 1.

Most requests are probably not initiated via full URL. So you're getting requests like `/api/something.json` and those do not get replaced.

You can use `URL` object to deal with all cases.

```
const origOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (...args) {
    if (typeof args[1] === 'string') {
        // will use example.com as a base if path is relative, ignore it if not
        const newURL = new URL(args[1], "http://www.example.com");
        newURL.host = "mywebsite.xxx";
        args[1] = newURL+"";
    }
    return origOpen.apply(this, args);
};
```

#### Problem 2.

`XMLHttpRequest` is not the only way to get AJAX data. Also consider replacing `fetch` async function in a similar manner.

Comment: I have tried the example code you've sent but it did not work...

Comment: If you maximum extent of effort you are willing to put into solving the problem together is "it did not work", then maybe it's better if you solve it alone. Also it sounds a lot like you missed my second point about `fetch`, which is also important.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to give the error. It says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'`

Comment: @beneems Ok, I fixed that, there was a missing `{` after the `if`. You still might need to write the code to override `fetch` behavior if some of the website uses it.

Comment: The website is on completely XHR, not fetch.

Comment: It works, but it redirected even URLs that I did not add to mine.

Comment: @beneems The title of your question says "all JSON requests", so yes, it redirects everything. If you want to make exceptions, use `if` statements or have an array of the blacklisted or white listed URLs. The URL object my solution uses allows you to check only the path, the query string etc. Check the docs at MDN.